# How do I get feathers from Chirri?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

In the Sealed Grounds area of Faron Woods, there are birds called Chirri flying around.  Targetting them and talking to Fi tells me "There is an 85% chance that its feathers can be used as some kind of material."

How do I get feathers from them?

I tried with the Bug Catching Net, but that's not working very well.

Comment: This really could be more for bug catching in general.  You will have a tough time catching Grasshoppers, Ciacadas and other such things that are very evasive.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You get the feathers by catching the **Chirri** with the **Bug Catching Net**.

Now I know you said it, catching them is hard, but it's actually easy once you know the secret.

To be able to catch anything that could be caught, you need to sneak up on the target (i.e., walk up to it) and swing your net at it.  It's easiest to swing sideways leading with the Wii Remote turned sideways.  This applies to anything that is evasive or would otherwise run/fly away.

What I would do is sneak up to it with your net out and touching the target.  Once you do that, swipe and it should be yours.

Here's a video demonstrating how you could do it:

Comment: I eventually figured it out... I was trying to catch them by swinging the net downwards, but instead, the trick is to turn the controller sideways and swing from one side to the other at ground level.

Comment: Also, Blue Feathers are considered a separate item and one should catch the blue bird every time you see it.

Comment: I don't think I ever got a `Blue Feather` from the blue ones, just a normal one.  My blue feather count was low and I always took the opportunity to catch stuff when I see them (and I saw the birds a lot).

Comment: I caught a blue bird up in Sealed Grounds and it gave me a blue feather.  Now I only see red and yellow birds there (I haven't left the room yet, though).

Comment: Hmm, maybe the blue birds are rare and I just never noticed them not being around as much.

Comment: I will note that the Blue Bird kept coming back until I caught it, though.

Comment: Get the bug net upgrade. It becomes much easier with the **Big Bug Net**.

Comment: To add to this.. I have found that, as long as you are moving slow enough, you can get close enough to actually touch the bugs/birds with the net.. Then it is as simple as wiggling your remote quickly to catch them.

Comment: @abelito: That's actually what I said.  ;)

Comment: @JeffMercado Haha, true that.. I must have skimmed too quickly :) Very good video