# How do I catch birds?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get feathers from Chirri?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37772/how-do-i-get-feathers-from-chirri)

A character in the game told me that I can catch birds with my bug net, for which I'll collect a feather. I have repeatedly tried to follow these instructions. Just before I get close enough to use my net, the birds fly away. **What is the best technique for catching birds?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Walk up to the birds ***very slowly, with your net vertical, at ground level***.  When you get within striking distance, swing the gently from right to left.

This technique applies to almost all the creatures you catch with the net.  Walk up to them slowly, net out and ready.

Answer (score 7):

Some tips from [this thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/960633-the-legend-of-zelda-skyward-sword/61154708):

> - Upgrade your net. This increases the likelihood that you will be successful.
> - Don't flick the net. Generally hold it up and to the right, then sweep it down diagonally. The entire motion should take about half a
>     second. A slower, sweeping motion seems to work better than quickly
>     flicking the net.
> - Slowly approach with the net already drawn. Watch the shadow as it goes over a bird. Swing straight down when the bird is where the shaft
>     of the net and the net connect going by the shadow. Also watch the
>     bird's movements. The blue ones usually sit longer than the others,
>     but not always. If you're close to catching one and it moves closer to
>     you, there is a good chance they'll all fly away.